# how to change visual selector color with xoria256 colorscheme

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight

I would like to change the visual highlight color in xoria256 colorscheme to the following:

make the background brighter but keep the color of the letters the same. I've seen people do it and I really like it.

I played with `Visual` and `VisualNOS` highlight groups but I was not able to figure out how to do it. I'd really appreciate any advice on the matter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

These are the current lines 75 and 77 of [xoria256.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/xoria256.vim/blob/master/colors/xoria256.vim#L75-L77):

```
hi Visual       ctermfg=255 guifg=#eeeeee ctermbg=96  guibg=#875f87
hi VisualNOS    ctermfg=255 guifg=#eeeeee ctermbg=60  guibg=#5f5f87
```

You will have to change the values according to [the xterm palette](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg).

1. Choose a color swatch,
2. use the number in the bottom left corner for `ctermfg` and `ctermbg`,
3. use the corresponding hexadecimal color for `guifg` and `guibg`,
4. do `:colorscheme xoria256` to reload your colorscheme and preview your changes.